# return function value with promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this function ror convert file to base64 for show file.

```
 ConvertFileToAddress(event): string {

    let localAddress: any;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target['files'][0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        localAddress = e.target['result'];
    };
    return localAddress;
}
```

And use it not components like this:

```
this.coverSrc=this.localization.ConvertFileToAddress(event);
```

But when log to the console the `this.coverSrc` it shows me `undefined`.

When I log in this bracket:

```
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        localAddress = e.target['result'];
    };
```

It show the value of `base64` but when I log the `localAddress` outside of `bracket` it shows me `undefined`.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnvtqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

How can I return the value of function and use it in other components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle that either by Promises or callback.

-- Using Call backs

```
ConvertFileToAddress(event, callback): string {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target['files'][0]);
    reader.onload = callback;
}

this.localization.ConvertFileToAddress(event, (e) => {
     this.coverSrc = e.target['result'];
});
```

-- Using Promises

```
ConvertFileToAddress(event): string {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target['files'][0]);
        reader.onload = (e) => {
             resolve(e.target['result']);
        };
    });
}

this.localization.ConvertFileToAddress(event).then((data) => {

   this.coverSrc = data;
});
```

You can make of Observable as well - you check the sample here - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo to reproduce the issue?